# How to convert assembly with multiple if statements to c code?

Tags: c, assembly

```
    cmp eax, 1
    je  .L3
    cmp eax, 4
    je  .L4
    jmp .L9
.L3:
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-16], 1
    jmp .L5
.L4:
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-16], 2
    jmp .L5
```

I need some help figuring out how exactly to convert this to C code. I've tried doing a nested if statement but it converts to

```
    cmp eax, 1
    je  .L3
    cmp eax, 4
    je  .L3
```

The code I tried was this

```
if (var1 != 1)
{
   if(var1!=4)
    {
        var2=1;
    }
}
```

Entire Assembly code for context

```
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 16
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 4
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-16], 0
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], 0
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
    cmp eax, 1
    je  .L3
    cmp eax, 4
    je  .L4
    jmp .L9
.L3:
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-16], 1
    jmp .L5
.L4:
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-16], 2
    jmp .L5
.L9:
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-16], 3
.L5:
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 0
    jmp .L6
.L7:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-12]
    add DWORD PTR [ebp-8], eax
    add DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 1
.L6:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-12]
    cmp eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-16]
    jl  .L7
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: Where is `.L9` ? It could be an  `else` clause to the inner `if` but it's not included in the assembly.

Comment: I added the rest of the assembly for context, I was trying to break it into sections to better understand it.

Answer (score 1):

That code should be assimilated to:

```
if (var1 == 1)
    goto l3; 
else if (var1 == 4) // we use the same value in eax so the same variable is being checked
    goto l4;
else goto l9;
l3: var2 = 1; goto l5;
l4: var2 = 2; goto l5;
l9: var2 = 3;
l5: ...
```

I should use a `switch` statement, as all the tests depend on the value of the `var1` variable (indeed, the value of `var1` is evaluated and stored into `eax`, and this is the value compared all the time) giving:

```
    switch (var1) {
    case 1:  var2 = 1; break;
    case 4:  var2 = 2; break;
    default: var2 = 3; break;
    }
```